# How to increase rate of probe request in 802.11?

Tags: request, code-injection, wifi, probe

i need to **increase the rate of probe request** from device not connected in wlan. I tried with injection packet (libpcap) but the device ignored all the request (Probe request, probe response, association, authentication, deauthentication, etc..).
Have you any suggestion for this problem?

EDIT:
I resolve the problem. The packet need CRC bit and use little endian in some frame's field. Is not to difference to create a sniffer in C, just create a good struct with correct size.